# Primefaces Slider component

Tags: primefaces, slider

Is there a way to do not use `InputText` in association with Primefaces `Slider` component (`for` attribute) ?

I just want to have only the slide bar.

I can use `InputHidden` component but is it another convenient way ?

Extending component ?

Comment: have you tried it without the `for` ?

Comment: yes but I receive "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "" ". I also tried for="#{null}" but it's the same

Comment: Sounds like somewhere in primefaces code they rely in the value attribute of the `for` element... you can take a look in their sources...(based on the exception)... so it seems that you must specify some element for the `for` attribute (unless somebody else know some other way...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the slider in Primefaces doesn't hold any values.

You could try to extend the component or create the one you want but it seems like a difficult work when you can use the InputHidden. The component translate to a div tag so it doesn't hold any values so, in any case, you'd have to add a field that posts its value with the form (if you create or extend the component).

What is the problem with InputHidden? Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: It's not a problem to use Inputhidden but it's a little bit "dirty" because value of this component is never used. However, I will use it. Thank you

Comment: That is the "problem" with the slider. It doesn't hold any values in itself since it is just a div tag. That is why the extra input field is needed

Comment: I will use the InputHidden field so. Thank you